# parse /etc/hosts for ip and hostname with puppet, and transpose into /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

Tags: ruby, puppet

I am kicking machines with cobbler to install redhat 6 and also put in hostname.
I am managing my machines with /etc/hosts file right now (may switch to dns in the future) and would like to have puppet (or anything that will work) parse through /etc/hosts and find my ip address and hostname (based on the hostname supplied by cobbler at kickstart).  The trick is that some machines have multiple IP's and hostnames in the /etc/hosts file, like such:

`#` Maintenance Network

```
192.168.80.192  testsrv01-maint
192.168.80.193  testsrv02-maint
192.168.80.194  testsrv03-maint
```

`#` Lights Out Network

```
192.168.120.192  testsrv01-ilo
192.168.120.193  testsrv02-ilo
192.168.120.194  testsrv03-ilo
```

`#` Primary Data Network

```
192.168.150.192  testsrv01-pri
192.168.150.193  testsrv02-pri
192.168.150.194  testsrv03-pri
```

`#` Secondary Data Network

```
192.168.200.192  testsrv01-sec
192.168.200.193  testsrv02-sec
192.168.200.194  testsrv03-sec
```

I need to capture each ip and hostname pair (in a line) and transpose into /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth* (eth1, eth2, eth3, ...).  Puppet will need to create as many ifcfg-eth* files as there are matches in /etc/hosts for the hostname.

I just need puppet to append the $IP and $hostname to the ifcfg-eth file, the rest of the content is common.

So how would I get 4x ifcfg-eth files for 'testsrv01', with puppet?

Answer (score 0):

Puppet is a very ill fit for this task. This calls for a script, which Puppet does not support. Puppet allows you to declare a piece of machine state that can portably enforced on different platforms.

The task is simple enough for a Shell or Perl Script.

With Puppet, it would entail the following scripts

1. writing custom facts to retrieve each address / hostname pair
2. devising a defined type to render such a pair into an ethX file

You'd possibly even need to generate the respective manifest, so that the appropriate interface index is chosen for each address.

All things considered, you would not make use of Puppet's strengths and suffer some of its weaknesses.